# Create Qpushbutton,Qlabel or else with code

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

In Qt i don't want to create button,label or else in design like drag and drop, but i want to create them with using code, so anyone can share the tutorial links for me about this code lessons please ?? sorry in advance for my bad question

Answer (score 0):

I loved [these video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63). Covers an awesome introduction into basic stuff, but a lot of advanced topics, too. I realize that your question includes a pyqt tag. Qt is really easy to handle with C++ though, especially for basic GUI programming. So if you don't absolutely have to use Python this is really worth getting into. On top of that, the python and C++ interface for programming Qt have a lot in common. So in any case it would not be a waste of time. Next time, take 5 minutes and search the web a little. There are tons of awesome tutorials out there, that are just a few key presses away using the search engine of your trust.